# How to plug in custom authentication into Linux?

Tags: linux, authentication

I would like to implement a custom way of authentication for Linux (Ubuntu, if this is specific). This should be some module written in C where my custom code would run, get the name/id of the user who wants to be authorized to access the machine and if returns FALSE, the use should not be allowed to login even after providing the valid password and username.

I somewhat know authentications can be plugged in Linux. Could anybody point me to the clear resource on how to develop the custom authentication? I tried to Google "plug in custom authentication ubuntu linux" without useful results.

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be a [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_MWG.html) module.

Comment: Do you know of any more recent guides than that?